# Nextjs Build Assets not loaded Correctly Using Nginx

Tags: nginx, next.js

I'm using Nginx, and here is my nginx config file

```
server {
  server_name my.yousico.com;

  gzip on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_types application/javascript application/x-javascript text/css text/javascript;
  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_min_length 256;
  client_body_buffer_size 20M;
  client_body_timeout 60s;
  client_max_body_size 20M;

  location /_next/static/ {
      alias /var/www/yousi-my/front/.next/static/;
      expires 365d;
      access_log off;
    }

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.yousico.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.yousico.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
 server {
    if ($host = my.yousico.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80;
  server_name my.yousico.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

For next JS, I am using the src/ folder version. When I run my product build locally all the assets load up fine, but when I deploy it with Nginx, a bunch of 404s start to appear so I assume something is wrong with my nginx.

Here is a screen shot of my network tab [image: network tab]

Answer (score 1):

This seems like you need to let nginx to proxy the request to the server. `alias` can sometimes cause issues with Nginx.

To fix the issue, you can try replacing the `alias` directive with a `proxy_pass` directive pointing to the backend server `http://localhost:3001;`.
This will proxy the request for `/_next/static/` to the server, which can handle the request and return the static files.

So replacing `alias /var/www/yousi-my/front/.next/static/;` by `proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;` in `location` may fix it.

```
...
# Other config 
 location /_next/static/ {
      # alias /var/www/yousi-my/front/.next/static/;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3001; # <--- notice the proxy_pass here
      expires 365d;
      access_log off;  
    }
# Other config 
...
```